# .htaccess, conflict in rules

Tags: .htaccess

I am just trying to understand how .htaccess work and what is right way of dealing with it and I have one problem. 
Here is part of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/css/(.*)$ /css/$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)/img/(.*)$ /img/$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)/js/(.*)$ /js/$2
```

Everything is looks fine and have worked ok, till I'll try to use TinyMCE that I have copied to js directory. It contain a lot of different subfolders, including img subfolders, and because of my rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)/img/(.*)$ /img/$2` it doesn't work properly. I know that I can just rename folders in TinyMCE, but I think that I am not dealing with .htaccess in right way.
Help me please.

Comment: What will the first `(.*)` usually contain? A language code?

Comment: Something like this "http://stackoverflow.com" . So just the name of the website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of matching any character in your rule, you can match one folder (allow every character except for `/`). That'll ensure that deep nested folders (e.g. `modules/tinymce/js/`) do not conflict with `en/js/`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/css/(.*)$ /css/$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/img/(.*)$ /img/$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/js/(.*)$ /js/$2
```